# use Maven to add info from MKS to Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, maven-scm, mks, mks-integrity

According to to the SCM Activity plugin info from the Sonar Webiste (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin), a connection to MKS should be possible. On the Maven site, MKS provider code also exists.

However, when I run mvn sonar:sonar in my command line, I get the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project example-it-jacoco-maven: Can not execute Sonar: Unsupported SCM: [svn:integrity]. Check compatibility at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin. Please check the parameter "sonar.scm.url" or the  section of Maven pom. -> [Help 1]

Do I need to somehow import the provider (coded into the pom.xml ?) or is there something wrong with my code in the pom:

```
scm:svn:integrity|myuser@mkssvr1:7001|#/SonarScm/TestCode
```

Anybody have an idea how to get this to work?

Cheers,

Kristian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that correct URL will look like : scm:integrity|myuser@mkssvr1:7001|#/SonarScm/TestCode

Comment: Thanks @Godin - that seemed to fix that.
Now its throwing an error relating to parsing the date it receives from MKS:

'[ERROR] [14:25:17.239] Failed to date string: 27.06.2012 MESZ
[DEBUG] [14:25:17.239] 26.06.2012 MESZ  1.1     Surname, Firstname(UserName)'